# How to enable all files to access your renamed directory in Eclipse project?

Tags: android, rename, preferences

I got tired of typing a very long auto-named directory from my Android SDK folder structure (into the command line), so I changed one of the names to shorten it and now  many other files cannot be accessed by my project when I work on it in Eclipse.

I went into Eclipse, into *Preferences*, and clicked on the *Android* category. It had a space where I could edit the directory structure name, so that fixed the files and folders in the *Android* section, but this did not update the other categories, like *General*, *Ant*, *C/C++*, *Help*... and all the other categories in that navigation menu of *Preferences*.

How do I update everything? Whenever I click on some of the other categories, it gives me an error, `An error has occurred when creating this preference page.` I know it is because I changed the name of that one folder only.

[image: Screenshot]

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one answered this, as it's very basic. Good thing I discovered the answer on my own. I found that you cannot rename a file in your project Workspace path of files just by opening the window and renaming. No, it has to be done through Eclipse. So, to rename a file, you must go to File > Switch Workspace > Other...

This will allow you to choose the directory in your Workspace folder that you want your project to be contained in. The errors I was getting was because I tried to rename a folder through Finder (on a mac). So I couldn't save correctly anymore, without getting errors. Once the workspace folder is changed properly, everything else updates and recognises the new folder. Just make sure you are in the right project, when you change your workspace folder.